# Spark UDF statistic

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

What is the best way to count the positive calls result of UDF? I have a UDF(java) that transforms a value of each field in a column and assigns it to the new column when four conditions are met. If not value is null.
It would be great to know which condition wasn't met, but for now, learning the total ratio of successful/unsuccessful calls is fine.
As this DF is quite massive is not possible to log every call, so I was thinking about creating a counter or cache as a part of UDF, and after the job finishing logging results or writing them to DB - the job runs every few hours on multiple workers, so it would not be expensive.

Comment: Please attach code of udf

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot add a code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [accumulators](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#accumulators) to create the statistic.

The following example contains two counters that are increased whenever the *complexUdf* returns an odd or even number respectively.

```java
SparkSession spark = ...

//create the two accumulators
LongAccumulator oddAccumulator = spark.sparkContext().longAccumulator("oddAccumulator");
LongAccumulator evenAccumulator = spark.sparkContext().longAccumulator("evenAccumulator");

//create the udf
//note: within the udf do not try to read the current values of the accumulators
spark.udf().register("complexUdf", (UDF1<Long, Long>)l -> {
  long result = l + 1;
  if( result%2==0) {
    evenAccumulator.add(1);
  }
  else {
    oddAccumulator.add(1);
  }
  return result;
}, DataTypes.LongType);

//create a toy dataset
Dataset<Long> df = spark.createDataset(Arrays.asList(1L, 2L, 3L), Encoders.LONG());

//call the udf
df.withColumn("processedData",callUDF("complexUdf", col("value")) ).show();

//in the driver process the value method of the accumulators return the expected values
System.out.println(String.format("the udf returned %d odd and even %d numbers", 
  oddAccumulator.value(), 
  evenAccumulator.value()));
```

Output:

```
+-----+-------------+
|value|processedData|
+-----+-------------+
|    1|            2|
|    2|            3|
|    3|            4|
+-----+-------------+

the udf returned 1 odd and even 2 numbers
```

Comment: thank you, that's very helpful. Wondering if there is any chance to do something in udf itself. The problem is that spark jobs are running in an established environment and probably it would be very difficult to change the service responsible for running many jobs.

Comment: not sure if I understand correctly what you mean with "to do something in udf itself". You collect the data inside of the udf. And after the processing of all rows is done, you read the value of accumulators (in the driver process).

Comment: In your solution Long Accumulators are instantiated in Spark Session. Let's say I don't have access to the spark job, only to UDF.

Comment: @jester: then it probably won't work. In what kind of environment would you be able to write UDFs but not able to change the driver code? This might be a hint that your architecture could be improved. In theory you could try to stream the statistic from the udf into a [Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/) topic. But when you don't have access to the driver I doubt that you are allowed to fire up a Kafka installation.